# Retrieving UserId from Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, asp.net-membership, membership

I am trying to retrieve the curent users `UserId` from the membership provider but something does not go the way I planned it to.Here is my code:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "forum_GetUsernameId";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username" , user);
var data = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

 @username nvarchar 
   AS
 SELECT UserId
 FROM aspnet_Users
 WHERE UserName = @username
```

While debugging I noticed that data returns `null` witch can not be posible unless `ExecuteScalar()` is not the method I should be calling.
Also user gets set to the curent username of that I am certain.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ditch the MembershipProviders before it's too late! They're useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `SqlMemberShipProvider` anyway it's simple:

```
Guid userID = (Guid) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SqlCommand.Parameter.Add()` method in your code. If you are using `Add()` method with two arguments, you have two choices;

```
Add(string, SqlDbType);
Add(string, object);
```

[image]

In this case, I think you are tried to use first `Add()` one. So, when I look in the database, `UserId` is a `uniquidentifier`.

[image]

Because of that, you should change your code to;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
```

There is nothing wrong to use `ExecuteScalar()` in your code. It returns first row of first column on your query. So, your query returns only one column with one row, there is no problem. But, `ExecuteScalar()` returns an object, maybe you might need convert to string with `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SqlMembershipProvider`, do what Tim said.

Otherwise, I don't think you should be using `ExecuteScalar()` to read a data from a field/column, try using `ExecuteReader`:

```
var data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
 //code goes here
}
```

Comment: No. In this case, ExecuteScalar is fine because his query returns only one column with one row. There is nothing wrong with ExecuteScalar.